# How to add expandable and collapsible fields in Excel based on formulae with totals respecting the primary field totals instead of column aggregates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

So consider a sample data (for illustration of what I want) which looks like this:

[image]

With this data when I am able to make a pivot table which looks like this:

[image]

While individual rows are pretty good, whatever aggregate I use for calculated metrics like Cost per Sale do not sit well with the totals. For example When I calculate total Cost per Sale it should be `40/70=0.57` Not 0.54 which is just the average of the column not accounting the quantity of each of them. Similar is the case with other calculated metrics. When I try to add new calculation, (values outside pivot table) I see the right values But I cannot expand collapse them with Pivot Table and it shows reference errors as soon as I expand, collapse the pivot table as follows:

[image]

So My question is: **Is there a way in excel, I can add expandable and collapsible fields based on formulae with totals respecting the primary field totals instead of column aggregates?**

### Data In tabular form (for reproducibility)

| Month | Sales | Cost | Cost per Sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jun-20 | $10.00 | $5.00 | $0.50 |
| Jul-20 | $15.00 | $7.00 | $0.47 |
| Aug-20 | $20.00 | $9.00 | $0.45 |
| Sep-20 | $25.00 | $19.00 | $0.76 |
| Jun-21 | $20.00 | $20.00 | $1.00 |
| Jul-21 | $40.00 | $20.00 | $0.50 |
| Aug-21 | $80.00 | $30.00 | $0.38 |
| Sep-21 | $50.00 | $23.00 | $0.46 |

Comment: Add a calculated field (or measure if using the data model) that is SUM(Cost)/SUM(Sales)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Average Cost of Sales takes the average over the values that show in the shown period if you like the column to show the values to be a formula construction you can add a calculated field to the pivot table as Rory already pointed out:

When the cursor is somewhere in the pivot table you are able to get access to the `PivotTable Analyze` tab in the ribbon. From there click `Fields, Items & Sets` and choose `Calculated Field`:
[image: CalcField1]

You are then able to name your Calculated Field (Pivot Column) (1) and write your calculation (2) `= SUM(Cost) / SUM(Sales)` in your case and add it to the fields (3):
[image: CalcField2]

The result is a calculated column that collapses along with the rest of the table:
[image: CalcField3]

Comment: Actually SUM(Cost)/SUM(Sales) did the trick as per @Rory's comment